# only first row can be returned with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

please help me to find out why only first row inserts in DB table when clicking inc and dec buttons. 
I want the DB to update immidiately every input on every click but only first item data is inserted into table. Even when i click another input field buttons.

Here's the code:
    ...

```
        <button class="btn btn-danger minus" name="item_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        <input class="text-center" type="number" name="item_1" id="item_1" value="0" />
        <button class="btn btn-success plus" name="item_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
...

        <button class="btn btn-danger minus" name="item_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        <input class="text-center" type="number" name="item_2" id="item_2" value="0" />
        <button class="btn btn-success plus" name="item_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

and jQuery, too:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.plus').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('name');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+id+']').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            var newVal = $('input[id='+id+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            var newVal = $('input[id='+id+']').val(0);
        }
    });
    $(".minus").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).attr('name');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+id+']').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            var newVal = $('input[id='+id+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            var newVal = $('input[id='+id+']').val(0);
        }
    });

$('button').click(function(){
var id = $('input').attr('id');
var newVal = $('input[id='+id+']').val();
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "update.php?pid="+id+"&qty="+newVal+"&uid="+id,
success: function() {
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
  }
});
});    
});
</script>
```

Comment: I got it myself!!! For those who face such problems: instead of $('input').attr('id') you should assign $(this).attr('name') to "id" variable.

Answer (score 0):

If someone met same problem, here's the solution:
    Change ***var id = $('input').attr('id');*** to 
    ***var id = $(this).attr('name');***

Because the first one gets the id from input field, while the correct one gets it from button clicked.